# Date time in select form

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a time picker in select form which is getting the actual time.

How can I do in select to pick option `time+15min`?

This is my code:

```
<select id="inputState" class="oke" ng-model="reservation.time">
    <option selected>{{date | date:'HH:mm'}}.</option>
    <option>{{date}}</option> <!--there i need option 15 min lates than before -->
</select>
```

Comment: In general, you could pre-build the "source" object before-hand and send it down with the request from the backend and bind it to the select. You also could build the options up through JavaScript and insert them after the empty select has loaded or give the user a datetime picker or similar to select from instead adding constraints/validation as needed.

Comment: Got it ! Thank's